Regarding Google sheets query Function
I create a Database in Google sheets like 'PB-Reconcile '
Reconciliation Date Area    Team    CRO Category    "Submission
Status "    MCL Number  Name    Total collection (Passbook) Total collection (ERP)  ERP balance Passbook Balance    Collection Variance     Balance Variance    Findings    Remarks
Then on a Report sheets I run query function
=QUERY('PB-Reconcile '!$A$1:$P$9966, "SELECT A, F, G, M, N, O, P WHERE B = '" & A3 & "'", 1)
Where B is Area & A3 is the data validation of area in my report sheet. I want if i cahnge the area than only those areas data will show up

all you need is =QUERY('PB-Reconcile '!A1:P9966, "SELECT A, F, G, M, N, O, P WHERE B = " & A3, 1)


Incase Area is a numerical value, try with removing the single quotes as such:
=QUERY('PB-Reconcile '!$A$1:$P$9966, "SELECT A, F, G, M, N, O, P WHERE B = " & A3 & "", 1)

